# React mouse follow listener messed up mouse enter and leave on component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component named `ProjectCard` and I also have `Cursor` component which is a custom cursor. When I hover over the ProjectCard I expect to have a **mouseenter** and when I move away from my cursor from `ProjectCard` i expect to have **mouseleave**. But that doesn't happen, what i got is multiple enter leave inside the `ProjectCard` instead of one enter when cursor comes inside the component, and one leave when i move cursor out of the component.

ProjectCard component:

```
const ProjectCard = () => {
  function mouseEnter(e) {
    console.log("mouse enter");
  }

  function mouseLeave() {
    console.log("mouse leave");
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="project"
      onMouseEnter={mouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={mouseLeave}
    >
      <img src="" alt="" />
      <div>
        <h5>Project number one</h5>
        <p>Testing the project description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectCard;
```

Cursor component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { gsap } from "gsap";

const isMobile = () => {
  const ua = navigator.userAgent;
  return /Android|Mobi/i.test(ua);
};

const Cursor = () => {
  if (typeof navigator !== "undefined" && isMobile()) return null;

  const cursorRef = useRef(null);
  const cursorFollowerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    addEventListeners();
    handleLinkHoverEvents();
    return () => removeEventListeners();
  }, []);

  const addEventListeners = () => {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  };

  const removeEventListeners = () => {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  };

  function moveCircle(e) {
    gsap.to(cursorRef.current, {
      x: e.clientX,
      y: e.clientY,
      duration: 0.3
    });
    gsap.to(cursorFollowerRef.current, {
      x: e.clientX,
      y: e.clientY,
      duration: 0.8
    });
  }

  function hoverFunc() {
    gsap.to(cursorRef.current, {
      opacity: 1,
      scale: 0,
      duration: 0.3
    });
    gsap.to(cursorFollowerRef.current, {
      scale: 2,
      duration: 0.3
    });
  }

  function unhoverFunc(e) {
    gsap.to(cursorRef.current, {
      opacity: 1,
      scale: 1,
      duration: 0.3
    });
    gsap.to(cursorFollowerRef.current, {
      scale: 1,
      duration: 0.3
    });
  }

  const onMouseMove = (e) => {
    moveCircle(e);
  };

  const handleLinkHoverEvents = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll("nav a").forEach((element) => {
      element.addEventListener("mouseenter", hoverFunc);
      element.addEventListener("mouseleave", unhoverFunc);
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="circle" ref={cursorRef}></div>
      <div className="circle-follow" ref={cursorFollowerRef}></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Cursor;
```

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-dubinsky-i6bym?file=/src/ProjectCard/index.js) link of the whole problem

Comment: Seems to work for me?  What are you expecting to happen that doesn't happen?  Or what happens that you do not expect.  Please add that information to your question.

Comment: Not really, i am getting multiple enter and leave if you try to move the cursor inside the ProjectCard. I added description in the question up there

Comment: I have created your question in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-river-niktu?file=/src/Cursor.js) and it seems to work as expected. Can you verify that it works as you expect? The one change I did make was moving the `useEffect` in the `Cursor` component above the early `return` since it was breaking the rules of hooks by using a hook conditionally.

Comment: @RobertCorponoi i updated your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-dubinsky-i6bym), please take a look now and you will see that there is a multiple mouse enter and leave if you move cursor inside project red area

Comment: @KrešimirGalić Thank you for doing that. I'm currently looking into the gsap docs because it seems to be related to the `gsap.to` calls. If you comment out the contents of the `moveCircle` function, it seems to work as expected.